# Copy files from Azure IaaS VM (File Storage) to Azure PaaS app service (Blob)

Tags: .net, azure, blob, integration, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Azure and would like some advise on the best integration approach.

- I need to grab some files (image and PDF files) from an Azure
  IaaS Windows VM - SFTP server(File Storage) and copy those to Azure Windows PaaS app 
  service (Blob Storage). The PaaS app service is for the external website for 
  which I have a storage account and need to copy the files to its blob 
  storage. The IaaS VM from where I need to grab the files is an internal 
  server.
- Also, as and when the files get added to Azure IaaS VM(File Storage), I
  need to ensure that those get copied over to the Azure PaaS app service (Blob 
  Storage). And I understand that I need to create some job(Azure Logic 
  app/Function app/Web job) that would check for the new files at some regular time
  interval and copy it over.

But I am not sure what would be the best to use in this case? Logic
app/Function app/Web job? If I decide to use Logic app, I believe I
may need to use some [Logic app connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list). But not sure which
connector can be used here? Is this kind of integration even possible?

Below are some of the posts I reviewed. Thank you for any suggestions in advance!

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/33001027-sftp-and-ftps-protocol-support-for-azure-files

[Copy file from remote server using SFTP straight to Azure blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004376/copy-file-from-remote-server-using-sftp-straight-to-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: There are SDKs for various languages that wrap the storage APIs, allowing you to upload content to blob storage (as well as command line tools). How you do this is really up to you, including where you host your code (web app, function, etc). Your question contains links to a whole lot of external topics, and your question (as written) is very broad.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response David. The reason I need to copy the files to PaaS app service (external website) is because I want to display those files via a URL. And this external website is built in .NET core and currently if I place any files manually in the blob, I can access it through the URL of that website. But I wanted to integrate it with the file storage on IaaS VM so that if any new file is added there, when my job(Logic app/Function app/Web job etc..) runs, it can pick the newly added file from IaaS VM  and put it on external website's blob.