# Can Azure blob storage is accessible as FTP?

Tags: azure, ftp, filezilla, azure-blob-storage

I wanted to use azure blob storage as ftp in filezilla. So that i can easily do my operations. Please can anybody help me out for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try not to look at new technologies with old knowledge: there are lots of tools that facilitate simple interaction with Blob Storage. And they're probably simpler than using FTP. :D
First result on searching: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992173/ftp-to-azure-blob-storage

Comment: Are you asking for the same as in [SFTP (and FTPS) protocol support for Azure Files](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/33001027-sftp-and-ftps-protocol-support-for-azure-files)? Note that people have developed solutions but apparently Azure does not support it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, we couldn't access the blob by using FTP.

The blob only provides client libraries and a REST interface that allows unstructured data to be stored and accessed at a massive scale in block blobs.

It will use http connection to connect to the azure storage.

Besides, azure provide a good tool to access azure storage, I suggest you could choose [storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to view the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use SFTP (SSH) to access Azure Container storage.  [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support) give details.

However, FTP(S) is not available natively; so to get that you need your own FTP service.

- You could run something (a VM or Container) to host the FTP service and have that setup to use the Azure Storage account as a backend (most FTP solutions would work natively with Azure Files by using SMB between the service and the backend storage; though there's likely a few that support other backends out there).
- Alternatively you can use SaaS solutions to implement this service layer; e.g. [CouchDrop](https://www.couchdrop.io/sftp-as-a-service) can have your Azure Storage account setup as its backend, and can presesnt this via a variety of protocols, including SFTP and FTP(S).  (Note: I have no experience with CouchDrop - that was just the first Google result when checking for this type of service; others are available so if you want to go this route, shop around).  Generally such services would be public facing, so there are additional security considerations over those solutions you can present within your internal network (though if you want the FTP service exposed publicly, this is a moot point).

Answer (score 0):

You can access Azure Storage containers using SFTP in Filezilla, but keep in mind that there's a cost associated with enabiling the feature. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support

I think you would be better using Azure Storage Explorer or one of the third party apps that allow you to browse azure storage. Filezilla Pro allows you to connect to azure storage - https://filezilla-project.org/filezilla_pro.php