# Download file from Azure file storage using FTP

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-storage

We have a system where the internet/network connectivity is not that good, as this is a vessel. In our case, we have to download a file from Azure file storage and we have to process this file in the vessel. I am actually trying to download this file using WebRequest but it is taking longer time (around 1 hour) to download but when I do an FTP transfer using TeamViewer, the file gets transferred in a couple of minutes. So my plan is to download the Azure file using FTP but I couldn't get any example for the same.Can someone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: When you say Azure File Storage, you mean Azure File Storage Service (that supports SMB protocol) and not Azure Blob Storage. Correct?

Comment: I mean Azure File Storage Service, not the Blob Storage

Comment: If that's the case, then you can mount a file share as a network drive and copy the files using explorer. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows. Will this solution work for you?

Comment: I have tried that already, basically what Azure does is, it actually shows only the folder and files metadata. If need to use the file, then Azure is actually downloading the file which is once again is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Azure File storage doesn't support FTP as of yet. You can find the request in user voice, please upvote it so the storage team can start planning it if they haven't already. **https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/33001027-sftp-and-ftps-protocol-support-for-azure-files**

You could however use storage explorer but since it didn't work for you, I'd recommend checking this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/a/40963889/6591675

> You can use nodeftpd combined with azure-storage-fs. nodeftpd is the FTP server written in Node.js and support third-party file system manager. azure-storage-fs is a file system manager that is designed to use for nodeftpd and talks to Azure Blob directly.